# SQL query data ordering

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am currently working on a web service which will fetch data from a database table and send it to the client in XML format. The tables in the database contain a large amount of data (millions of rows). Therefore, pagination and compression algorithms have been implemented so the data is compressed and split into multiple pages.

My question is, if I call some query say

```
select t.* 
from (select * 
      from table_name) t 
where rownum > start_val 
  and rownum <= end_val
```

multiple times without ordering, will the data and order of the rows fetched every time I execute for same `start_val` and `end_val` be the same (if no new values are added in the database)?

Edit: if no, then what could be more efficient way to get paginated data from the table as right now I am fetching the data by executing

```
select t.* 
from 
    (select * 
     from table_name 
     order by 1) t 
where 
    rownum > start_val and rownum <= end_val
```

for each page and the query is taking 5-6 minutes to execute.

I have read-only access to the tables.

Comment: There is no garanteed order without an `order by`

Comment: Furthermore, even if that order _were_ guaranteed (which it's not), the order might change if new records were inserted in between your calls.

Comment: And [`rownum>start_val` won't match anything if `start_val` is greater than 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32959569/266304); so you need a subquery (inline view), and that needs to include ordering.

Comment: is there an IDENTITY column?

Comment: there is no IDENTITY column

Comment: can you modify data schema and add a new column?

Comment: I have read-only access to the table

Comment: If your query is slow.. optimise it. For example there might be a more suitable column to order on than `1`. What indexes exist on the table?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no ways if you ony have read-only access. You can ask parner (manage database) have some edit that table, can user materialized view, oracle timestamp or add id.

Answer (score 0):

Your client will probably not page through all the million of records, so if an often scenario is to get say less than the first 100 pages (assuming a 10 rows per page)
you may optimize for it.

I assume your first column (`ORDER BY 1`) is `COL1`

Find a value of `COL1` such as in the table are at least 1000 rows with a smaler value.
In my case it is the value `201110`

```
select count(*) from myTab where col1 < 201110;
 COUNT(*)
----------
      1000
```

Note that the 1000 row covers the 100 pages with 10 rows each.
Now you can optimize the access for the first 100 pages using following query:

```
SELECT  
    col1, col2, rownum rn
FROM myTab
where col1 < 201110
order by id
)
select * from page
where rn > 10 and rn <= 20
;
```

The crucial part is

```
 FROM myTab
 where col1 < 201110
```

Even if there is no index in `col1` and you will be forced to do a FTS, you will **sort only the 1000 records and not the full millions**.

Note that sort is much expensive that full scan, so **limiting sort is the key.**

Also starting from [12c](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55637) you may use the OFFSET clause for pagination

```
SELECT  
    col1, col2 
FROM myTab
where col1 < 201110
order by col1
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```